# CTE Error : Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Execute Following query :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CAST('" + mindate+ "' as varchar(255))  as fdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, fdate) as date)
    FROM cte
    WHERE fdate < '" + tday+"'
)
SELECT COUNT(fdate) AS Fdate
FROM cte left join tbl_Attendence on cte.fdate = tbl_Attendence.Datess
where tbl_Attendence.Datess is null
```

But I am ending with the following error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "fdate" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: Since you've got explicit casts there, how can you be confused? You're saying that `fdate` is `varchar(255)` in the first part of the CTE and `date` in the recursive part.

Comment: both fdate and date have different datatype that-sway its give error

Comment: If you're going to write this sort of query more than once, it's usually worth investing the small amount of time required to create a calendar table. Populated with one row per day, it can then easily be used for a query like this and 20 years worth of data is still less than 10000 rows total.

Comment: There are lots of mistake in the query, you simply select a string varchar value "+ mindate +" as fdate and using CTE try to cast that varchar value into date type which is not possible in any language. I will suggest you make a simple query with cast values so you able to understand what you doing wrong in there or try to explain your requirement and give a scenario for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is your original query:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CAST('" + mindate+ "' as varchar(255)) as fdate 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, fdate) as date) 
    FROM 
        cte 
    WHERE 
        fdate < '" + tday+"' 
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(fdate) AS Fdate 
FROM 
    cte 
    left join tbl_Attendence on cte.fdate = tbl_Attendence.Datess 
where 
    tbl_Attendence.Datess is null
```

The problem is that the first `SELECT` inside the CTE is `VARCHAR(255)` type, while it's union counterpart (the 2nd `SELECT` inside the CTE) is a `DATE` type. Since you are adding these results together, data types must match.

There's a `WHERE` (`fdate < '" + tday+"'`) that's comparing string values. Seems to me that you want this as dynamic SQL. It won't work on plain SQL without building the string first.

I can't suggest a solution since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

---

If what Damien suggests is right, you can use the following to find out amount of dates missing from `tbl_Attendence`:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2018-01-01'

DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = GETDATE()

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        @MinDate as fdate 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, 1, fdate) as fdate
    FROM 
        cte 
    WHERE 
        fdate < @MaxDate
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(fdate) AS Fdate 
FROM 
    cte 
where 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'not in tbl_Attendence' FROM tbl_Attendence AS T WHERE T.Datess = cte.fdate)
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: If I've decoded the logic correctly, it's "find the number of days between these two dates where no Attendence entry exists"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yup, seems like it.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions), you have:

> The data type of a column in the recursive member must be the same as
>   the data type of the corresponding column in the anchor member.

Check all the rules and be sure that you are following them.

Answer (score 0):

in the union all the records must have the same columns and the same name of the columns, you have used fdate and date, you should to use the same name for the column

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CAST('" + mindate+ "' as varchar(255))  as fdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, fdate) as fdate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE fdate < '" + tday+"'
)
SELECT COUNT(fdate) AS Fdate
FROM cte left join tbl_Attendence on cte.fdate = tbl_Attendence.Datess
where tbl_Attendence.Datess is null
```

Comment: Union's result sets don't have to match in column name, just amount and type. Try this and it will work: `SELECT 1 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS B`.